# Error importing database in PostgreSQL: 'psql: authentication method 10 not supported" FAILURE'

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, import, backend

I am a total beginner. I'm trying to import a database (named "baseball_database.sql") on postgreSQL, with Postbird client, but I'm getting an import error: "psql: authentication method 10 not supported" FAILURE

I tried reinstalling the latest versions of both many times, Postbird (v0.8.4) and Postgres (Version 14), and also tried it with 3 different databases, but got the same error every time.

Below are the error and the specs, in case required:

[image: Error]

[image: Specs]

[image: Specs 2]
[image: Specs 3]

Comment: https://github.com/psequel/psequel/issues/221. Check whether answers in this issue link helpful to you.

Comment: What os and how did you install?  Where did those last two images come from?

Comment: @jjanes I have windows 11 pre-installed. I took screenshots from the control panel, installed apps/ software section.

Comment: The problem is that you are using an old, outdated version of the PostgreSQL client library. Upgrade that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How do I do that? I don't even know which client library I'm using.

Comment: You could ask the software vendor. If you installed the client library as part of the product, it is their bug.

Answer (score 3):

Postbird seems to come bundled with those scarily ancient versions of psql.exe and pg_dump.exe.  I would ponder whether I really want to use such a poorly organized product.

You can find the locations of those binaries in the postbird program directory, and over-write them with the ones from your modern installation.  Or you could change your database to use md5 authentication rather than SCRAM.  Or just not use Postbird.